# Save just changed directory to file

Tags: windows, cmd

How could you save the freshly changed directory to a file? I thought this would work, but it executes the commands in the same directory:

```
cd desired_dir && echo foo && echo %CD% > path.txt
```

Is there an operator like "do this. after finishing, do this with the new parameters" in cmd?

I use this command to get the directory for a web-based commandline (using php). I read the current path from a file, execute some code and save the new path into a file.

Comment: Are you referring to the `echo %CD%` giving the original directory instead of the new one? Did you try `cd desired_dir && echo foo && cd > path.txt`

Comment: Cool - I reposted as the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `echo %CD%` will "lock in" the `%CD%` value that exists at the time the command is parsed. If you want the "real time" directory, use this:

```
cd desired_dir && echo foo && cd > path.txt
```